# Mongodb Aggregation pipeline: is it possible to have different $match on the same value and show both on the same output?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am new to Mongodb, been working on an aggregation pipeline, lets say I have the following books collections :

```
{ "bname" : "BOOKA-2020", "PRICE" : 10 , "REF":"A" }
{ "bname" : "BOOKA-2020", "PRICE" : 20 , "REF":"A" }
{ "bname" : "BOOKB-2020", "PRICE" : 30 , "REF":"B" }
{ "bname" : "BOOKB-2020", "PRICE" : 40 , "REF":"B" }

{ "bname" : "BOOKA-2021", "PRICE" : 50 , "REF":"A" }
{ "bname" : "BOOKA-2021", "PRICE" : 60 , "REF":"A" }
{ "bname" : "BOOKB-2021", "PRICE" : 70 , "REF":"B" }
{ "bname" : "BOOKB-2021", "PRICE" : 80 , "REF":"B" }
```

I want the make two separate $match to output the sum of the books price based on the year so I ended up with someting like this in the pipeline :

```
{
  $match: {
    bname: /2020/ 
}, {
  $group: {
    _id: '$REF',
    PriceSum2020: {
      $sum: '$PRICE' ,
    },
  },
}, .........
```

> (I dont have direct access to the year, plus I am not allowed to
> change   the schema so I ended up using regex)

this works as expected! it show the book's name and the price sum of the year 2020, but I want to do the same for 2021 and have it show too in the result, the thing is when I do the second $match it overrides the previous $match only show 2021,

I Think it may be achieved by using $faucet or $bucket but I couldn't figure it out..

my expected output is :

```
{ "REF" : "A", "PriceSum2020" : 30, "PriceSum2021" : 110 }
{ "REF" : "B", "PriceSum2020" : 70, "PriceSum2021" : 150 }
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can use `bname: {$in : [/2020/, /2021/]}` ?

Comment: I did already, will sum both years prices, I want sums to be seperate as I mentioned, Thanks tho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query

- add a year field
- group by REF+year and sum the prices
- group by REF and push the total prices in each year
- the rest is to produce the exact output you need, i think you dont need them but i added them
- map to turn the prices array to `k,v` pairs and convert into {}
  with the field names `price+year`
- and then move that to root (merge with root)

[Playmongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=62c967f4befa88fe45d75ec6)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$set": 
   {"year": 
     {"$toInt": {"$arrayElemAt": [{"$split": ["$bname", "-"]}, 1]}}}},
 {"$group": 
   {"_id": {"REF": "$REF", "year": "$year"}, "price": {"$sum": "$PRICE"}}},
 {"$group": 
   {"_id": "$_id.REF",
    "prices": {"$push": {"year": "$_id.year", "price": "$price"}}}},
 //Maybe you dont need the bellow 
 {"$project": 
   {"REF": "$_id",
    "_id": 0,
    "prices": 
     {"$arrayToObject": 
       [{"$map": 
           {"input": "$prices",
            "in": 
             {"k": {"$concat": ["price", {"$toString": "$$this.year"}]},
              "v": "$$this.price"}}}]}}},
 {"$replaceRoot": {"newRoot": {"$mergeObjects": ["$prices", "$$ROOT"]}}},
 {"$project": {"prices": 0}}])
```

Comment: Once again thank you for helping in this. However, I still have another question on a very similar problem, please take a look at it if you have time!
[Question link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72921370/mongodb-aggregation-pipeline-different-match-to-show-different-results-on-the)